# How to use a UDF on flink sql client after generating the jar file?

Tags: java, sql, jar, apache-flink, avro

I have this code below in java that takes a specific schema 'schema.asvc" and i try to decode the data from avro format to the schema's format.

```
package com.example;
   
   import org.apache.avro.Schema; import
   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData; import
   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader; import
   org.apache.avro.io.Decoder; import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
   import org.apache.flink.table.functions.ScalarFunction;
   
   import java.io.IOException; import java.nio.file.Files; import
   java.nio.file.Paths;
   
   public class AvroDecoderFunction extends ScalarFunction {
       private Schema schema;
   
   
       public AvroDecoderFunction(String schemaFilePath) throws IOException {
           this.schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(schemaFilePath))));
       }
   
       public GenericData.Record decodePayload(byte[] payload) throws IOException {
           Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(payload, null);
           GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(this.schema);
           return reader.read(null, decoder);
       } }
```

first I would like to know is this code reasonable to do such treatment ? Then after creating the jar file, how can I launch the flink sql client with this jar and how to use this function knowing that I would like to use it on a specific field 'payload' ?

Please any help is appreciated.